# Is there a way to nullify a escaping closure without calling it?

Tags: swift, escaping, closures

I'm looking for a way to nullify an escaping closure without calling it.

```
func should(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
    if something {
        completion = nil
    } else {
        completion()
    }
}
```

As long as I understand, the escaping closure can be called after the `should` function is finished, it will alive until it is get called.

Is there a way to nullify the closure(and captured values) without calling it?

Comment: I don't know if it works, but could you add a locale variable inside which might contain the closure and call that instead?

Comment: @Michael I'm not sure what you mean. Can you add a code for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the closure is in fact not escaping, since you're not assigning it to anything outside the function, so there's no need to nullify:

```
func should(completion: () -> Void) {
    if !something {
        completion()
    }
}
```

But if it was escaping, say by assigning it to a property, then you could nullify the property to release it:

```
class Foo {
   let fn: (() -> Void)?

   func should(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
      fn = completion
   }

   func executeAndRelease() {
      fn?()
      fn = nil
   }
}
```

Comment: I simplified the logic and the method is from protocol so I can't change.

Comment: Maybe you oversimplified, but in your specific example, there's no need to do anything. And if it does escape, then yes - you could set it to `nil`

Comment: Doesn't setting `completion` to `fn` make retain count +1 and -1 when `fn=nil`?

Comment: the parameter `completion` doesn't live after the function exists

Comment: Even it is @escaping? So the compiler nullify it unless the completion is not get called after the function exits?

Comment: The problem is how does compiler knows when the captured value by the closure should be released? The default closure parameter is non-escaping so the compiler know when it will be released. But for the escaping closure parameter, how can we handle it?

Comment: Just because it's marked as `@escaping` doesn't mean it has actually escaped. If you are not storing a reference to it outside of the function, then the only reference to it is the local parameter, which is released as soon as the function exits. I'm not sure how else to say what I've been saying - if it is not assigned outside of the function, then it has not escaped - nothing needs to be done